# Iphone notifying PC computer when there is a new message received on iphone

Tags: iphone, notifications, message

I am planning to work on this iphone application but I am not sure whether it is feasible or not. The app goes this way. When I get a message on my iphone, itouch or ipad and if it is in the proximity of a desktop computer, I should get an update on my desktop computer that I got a message. I just have an idea about this app but no idea as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do this unless you have a jailbroken iPhone.  I haven't done anything like this, but I would imagine you would have to bind into the notification part and verify it's an SMS.  Then see if you can "ping" the computer to check if you're both on the network and then push a notification to the app on the computer (which would obsiously have to be running).